# Magento invoice email customization

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, email

I am trying to setup a Invoice email template in Magento, and I see that the most of the informations I want is displayed.

However, I would like to display the shopping cart content with only the item's name and summary of the cart. I have some kind of product description added in the cart with every product, I don't want that part to be displayed in the email template.

I see that the cart is displayed in email template with:

```
{{layout area="frontend" handle="sales_email_order_invoice_items" invoice=$invoice order=$order}}
```

Is there a way to display only items, and without the description for every product?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are heading in the right direction. Since you found the handle, a little search and you can find that the `sales_email_order_invoice_items` handle is in the `sales.xml` file.

```
<sales_email_order_invoice_items>
    <block type="sales/order_email_invoice_items" name="items" template="email/order/invoice/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_default</block><template>email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="sales/order_invoice_totals" name="invoice_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
            <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</sales_email_order_invoice_items>
```

- The `email/order/invoice/items.phtml` file is responsible for main template of the invoice.
- The `email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml` is most probably what you are looking for, it will be used for each product to display its info.

Thus just copy the `email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml` into your own template folder and change whatever you need changed in that file.

Comment: As @Dan correctly mentions, you will need some form of code customization, you cannot do what you want without copying the template or create your own.

Comment: Ok, but I dont need to copy the file, I can also edit the existing one, right? 

And also, it wont take affect to the orders email templates if I got this right, thats in different folder and phtml file?

Comment: @JosipGvozdic You don't HAVE to per se, but it is bad practice to edit core files. It will be very hard to track changes later on as when you upgrade your magento installation, your changes will be lost.

Comment: @PetarDzhambazov, Good explanation. can you tell me how to pass weight attribute to invoice email to the customer at this exactly path?