# How to modify invoice email template code?

Tags: magento-1.9

How to modify invoice email template code?

how to find the invoice email file path.

Comment: May i know what exact information u want to customize in the invoice email   and please specify the details more so that i can help you accordingly

Comment: please check this link might be useful for you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2722/magento-invoice-email-customization

Comment: I want to add one row Advance Deposite  ₹1,000.00 ,Price should be dynamic. Below Shipping & Handling . In invoice email template i want to display .

Comment: please follow the below steps and confirm me whether u got the output thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** 
Enable invoice email from the backend

```
System=>Configuration=>Sales=>Sales Emails=>Invoice=>Enabled (yes)
```

**Step 2:**

Please find the below function from the path **app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php**

```
public function sendEmail($notifyCustomer = true, $comment = '')
```

**Screen Shot:** 
[image]
**Step 3:** 
Please specify the {{var advance_deposite}} in your **invoice_new.html**

from the file path **app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/invoice_new.html** 
as shown in below

```
<td class="method-info">
 <h6>Advance Deposite</h6>
 {{var advance_deposite}}
</td>
```

**Screen Shot:**
[image]

Please follow the tips:

=>Try in the dev site

=>Use mage::log whether you are able to getting the value or not in the invoice.php

=>invoice send mail [image]

Comment: I am unable to get the value of advance deposite.

Comment: whether the value has been saved in "sales_falt_order" or sales_flat_invoice tables please check the same in database column and mention the 'get' method accordingly.

Comment: please check and mention the column name so that i can mention the  the get method here

Comment: Sounds great, please accept or like the answer so that it will be helpful to others. Happy coding and thanks

Comment: All the best and happy coding

Comment: Advancd deposite is displaying but  currency symbol is not displaying and i want to display advance deposte below shipping and handling.

Comment: For ex: please use like this $advanceDeposite=Mage::helper('core')->currency($order->getAdvanceDeposite(), true, false);

Comment: please confirm whether you are able to get the price symbol or not?

Comment: ok that's great news all the best.